# Need to merge nullable double into non nullable method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created 2 `ActionResult`, both of which accepting the same parameters except one needs to be nullable and one doesn't. the problem arises when I pass my form submission to my `ActionResult`, c# can't differentiate between which `ActionResult` to use. Would someone be able to inform me how I can merge these two together so I can have one `ActionResult` that accepts a nullable double without causing me a "`Cannot implicitly convert between double? and double`"

My non nullable ActionResult is as follows:

```
public ActionResult Convert(double p1, string p2)
{
    Exercise07IndexViewModel model = new Exercise07IndexViewModel { Conv = p1 };

    if( p2 == "C2F" )
    {
        var math = ((9 * p1) / 5 ) + 32;
        Exercise07ConvertViewModel c2f
        = new Exercise07ConvertViewModel { OriginalValue = p1, OriginalUnit = "°C", ConvertedValue = math, ConvertedUnit = "°F", Convert = p2 };
        return View("Convert", c2f);
    }
    else if (p2 == "F2C")
    {
        var math = ((p1 - 32) * 5) / 9;
        Exercise07ConvertViewModel f2c
        = new Exercise07ConvertViewModel { OriginalValue = p1, OriginalUnit = "°F", ConvertedValue = math, ConvertedUnit = "°C", Convert = p2 };

        return View(f2c);

    }
    else if (p2 == "oz2g")
    {
        var math = 28.35 * p1;
        Exercise07ConvertViewModel oz2g
        = new Exercise07ConvertViewModel { OriginalValue = p1, OriginalUnit = "oz", ConvertedValue = math, ConvertedUnit = "g", Convert = p2 };
        return View("Convert", oz2g);
    }
    else if (p2 == "g2oz")
    {
        var math = 0.035 * p1;
        Exercise07ConvertViewModel g2oz
       = new Exercise07ConvertViewModel { OriginalValue = p1, OriginalUnit = "g", ConvertedValue = math, ConvertedUnit = "oz", Convert = p2 };
        return View("Convert", g2oz);
    }
    else if (p2 == null || p2 == String.Empty || p2 == "ScaleNotSupported")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Convert", model);
    }
}
```

And my nullable ActionResult, that I need to include in the above:

```
public ActionResult Convert(double? p1, String p2)
{
    if(p1 == null)
    {
        return RedirectToRoute(new
        {
            controller = "Index",
            action = "Index"
        });
    }
    return View();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, it is simple: There is an implicit conversion from `double` to `double?`, so you can get away only with the nullable-double method:

```
public ActionResult Convert(double? np1, string p2)
{
    if (np1 == null)
    {
        return RedirectToRoute(new
        {
            controller = "Index",
            action = "Index"
        });
    }

    var p1 = np1.GetValueOrDefault();
    Exercise07IndexViewModel model = new Exercise07IndexViewModel { Conv = p1 };

    if( p2 == "C2F" )
    {
        var math = ((9 * p1) / 5 ) + 32;
        Exercise07ConvertViewModel c2f = new Exercise07ConvertViewModel { OriginalValue = p1, OriginalUnit = "°C", ConvertedValue = math, ConvertedUnit = "°F", Convert = p2 };
        return View("Convert", c2f);
    }
    else if (p2 == "F2C")
    {
        var math = ((p1 - 32) * 5) / 9;
        Exercise07ConvertViewModel f2c = new Exercise07ConvertViewModel { OriginalValue = p1, OriginalUnit = "°F", ConvertedValue = math, ConvertedUnit = "°C", Convert = p2 };
        return View(f2c);
    }
    else if (p2 == "oz2g")
    {
        var math = 28.35 * p1;
        Exercise07ConvertViewModel oz2g = new Exercise07ConvertViewModel { OriginalValue = p1, OriginalUnit = "oz", ConvertedValue = math, ConvertedUnit = "g", Convert = p2 };
        return View("Convert", oz2g);
    }
    else if (p2 == "g2oz")
    {
        var math = 0.035 * p1;
        Exercise07ConvertViewModel g2oz = new Exercise07ConvertViewModel { OriginalValue = p1, OriginalUnit = "g", ConvertedValue = math, ConvertedUnit = "oz", Convert = p2 };
        return View("Convert", g2oz);
    }
    else if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(p2) || p2 == "ScaleNotSupported")
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return View("Convert", model);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All nullable types have the same properties that you can use to convert them to their non-nullable equivalents, e.g.:

```
public ActionResult Convert(double? p1, String p2)
{
  if (p1.HasValue)
  {
    var d = p1.Value;
    // Do the equivalent of Convert(d, p2)
  }
  else
  {
    // Handle the null p1.
  }
}
```